# AWS Cognito signup page that isn't public facing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm currently working on a way to hand off creation of users in a Userpool to my product team so that I don't need to handle user creation and password resets anymore. The key here is that the tool I give them needs to be simple and non-technical, and not require them going into was with permissions, knowing how to use Cognito and make the users within Cognito. This also needs to *not* be a public facing signup (i.e. the folks using the page need to never see the signup form). This is for my team's developer documentation which integration partners cannot see until they meet with us.

Looking at all the possibilities and the AWS API documentation has been making my head spin, though. I'm not sure what the best way to create this tool - the Cognito SDK? The AWS AdminCreateUser API? Or is there a way to set this up with the built in signup page UI provided by Cognito but host the signup page elsewhere (somewhere that people who look at our documentation will never see a signup page)?

Please let me know what your approach would be if given this problem. I'm a pretty green jr. developer and don't have much experience with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use the built-in Cognito UI to create users, you would need to come up with an alternative custom solution. Mind you will need to implement all features you expect from such user administration tool, including login for administrators into the tool itself.

With AWS Cognito APIs you can do everything native UI can do (and even more, like setting user attributes which is not available at Cognito console).

Quick google search led me to this project: https://github.com/jzoric/cognito-user-manager-ui which may be a good starting point if you decide to go this route.

Alternatively you may want to explore other SAAS solutions (Auth0 or Okta) which may provide better native UI out of the box.